# Parsing array recursively in Swift 4

Tags: swift, swift4

I'm trying to implement Quick Sort in Swift and having issues recursively parsing the array into the `quick_sort` function. I'm receiving the error:

```
error: ambiguous subscript with base type '[String]' and index type 'CountableRange<Int>'
```

The function is:

```
func quick_sort(_ array: inout [String]) {
    if array.count > 0 {
        let pivot = array[0]
        var (left, right) = partition(&array, pivot)
        quick_sort(&array[0..<left])
    }
}
```

The error is occurring on the line `quick_sort(&array[0..<left])`.

 It may have to do with it potentially being an ArraySlice?

Comment: You're correct. The line gives ArraySlice type where you need to convert it to array. But I'm not sure if you can do that without creating a new array. I suggest just edit your function signature to accept startIndex & endIndex for your next iteration. In that case, you case still pass the array as reference.

Comment: Generally, it's better to make a `mutating func` instance member in an extension, than a free function with an `inout` parameter.

Answer (score 0):

When you slice an `Array`, you get an `ArraySlice`. When you slice an `ArraySlice`, you get another `ArraySlice`. This property, that `T.SubSequence == T`, is vital to making a recursive algorithm like this, so that you only have to work with a single type.

You need your recursive function work with `ArraySlice`, but you can make a wrapper function that takes an Array and does the necessary conversion.

```
func quickSort(_ array: inout [String]) {
    func quickSort(_ slice: inout ArraySlice<String>) {
        if let first = slice.first {
            var (left, right) = partition(&slice, pivot)
            quickSort(&slice[0..<left]) // This part of the algorithm will break...
        }
    }

    quickSort(ArraySlice(array))
}
```

Comment: `quickSort(ArraySlice(array))` – this will not work because `quickSort` takes an `inout` parameter.

Comment: @TimVermeulen Yeah, a local copy will need to be made.

Comment: You could also do `quickSort(&array[...])` :)